# Log4j - configuring AsyncAppender in log4j.properties

Tags: log4j

I've seen tons of materials on how to use AsyncAppender in log4j.xml. However, I can't use a xml configuration, as I'm using Jboss Fuse - and this technology only allows .properties configuration.

Is there a way to translate the following configuration to .properties?

```
<appender name="async" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
  <param name="BufferSize" value="500"/>
  <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</appender>
```

I'd imagine that a solution looks somewhat like that:

```
log4j.appender.async=org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender
log4j.appender.async.appenders=console
```

Comment: Does this mean the AsyncAppender requires XML configuration? Can .xml and .properties co-exist?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK AsyncAppender requires XML configuration. In my case I was using ops4j-logging (bundled with Jboss Fuse), so I was able to use an ops4j feature described in the answer, to use properties configuration for this problem.

Comment: I ended up writing the config programmatically. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation, this is not possible in property configurer:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html

However, as I'm using Jboss Fuse and Jboss Fuse is using ops4j pax-logging, it has been solved and the configuration I submitted

```
log4j.appender.async.appenders=console
```

does work in Jboss Fuse